# To make an android application that can show number of hits of any website

Tags: android

Hello I am developing an application in android that can represent the number of hits of a web site (eg. google,facebook) etc in a graph. in my app's activity if i request so.

If there is any suggestion please inform me how to do this task in android.

thanks

Mohit

Answer (score 0):

you have to mention the id which you got from google analytics after login into your program and then call the tracker.dispatch()